# grammar in: でもね、私は きれいで かわいい この色が 好き

Tags: grammar

i couldn't understand the sentence until i read the translation, mainly because of the order of the words..does で means 'and' here? and why is the sentence translated as "But, I liked this pretty, cute color."
thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

で is used to join multiple adjectival words or phrases and is used directly 
after a な-adjective or noun-based adjectival clause.

> 先生はハンサムでお金持ちで頭がいい方です。 Sensei is handsome, rich, and a smart person.

Comment: 「きれいで」は、形容動詞「きれいな」の連用形・・・って国語の授業では習うんですが、日本語学習者はそうは教わらないんですかね、やっぱ・・

Comment: thank you! i understand that part, but what confuses me is that この色が好き isn't somehow link to the sentence thus I don't understand why the whole sentence means what it means. hmm.

Comment: Let's partition it this way: きれいでかわいい（pretty and adorable）この色（this color）が好き（I like）, which when rearranged for English would be: I like/this color/(that's)pretty and adorable.

Answer (score 1):

You know how like some people start to say something, change mid sentence and say something else, but then circling back? If you read 「私はこの色がすき」the link makes perfect sense. Now break the link, like the speaker, and interject why the color is liked. Or perhaps pretty and cute are the ways in which the speaker is describing the particular color they like. (Not all colors are pretty and cute). I'm more like the person the speaker is speaking with as I don't really fancy such a color. (I lie).